# ESS R workflow with package management in renv (or Packrat)

Tags: org-mode, ess, r, package-development

I do all my R development in Emacs via `org-mode` and ESS. All of my R projects are managed out of a single `org-mode` document (studies.org). Each project has a header and is tangled to its own project directory. This looks something like:

```
* A study in R
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args: :tangle ~/org/studies/study_in_R
  :END:

  #+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R* :dir :results silent

  setwd("~/org/studies/study_in_R")

  #+END_SRC
```

As I develop each project, I build functions that get moved to my function library (code.org). This gets tangled each time I save it and contains every (reusable) function I have ever written. It looks something like this:

```
* AppleScript
* Emacs Lisp
* Python
* R
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args: :tangle ~/Code/R.R
  :END:

  * Function 1
  * Function 2
    ...
* Shell
* Settings
```

Recently, I discovered `Packrat` and its successor `renv`. I love the idea of ring-fencing my projects into virtual environments. But I'm struggling with the implementation.

So here are a couple of questions:

1. What is the best way to migrate my legacy R packages into the `renv` packages cache?
2. And what about my R function library? Should I tangle this into one giant `omniverse` which gets installed into all of my R projects? Or would that defeat the purpose of segmenting my packages? If I leave it as is (tangled to `~/Code/R.R` and loaded through `.Rprofile`) is `renv` smart enough to pick out `library()` calls from different functions that my projects reference from `R.R`?
3. If I am developing my code in `studies.org` (which is not in my projects directory) and this is referencing additional functions from `code.org` (also not in my projects directory) how does `renv::hydrate()` know to auto-add dependencies to my project? Do I need to tangling r projects to their respective project folders first?
4. There are some packages that I may want to share with all projects (`roxygen2`, `devtools`, `usethis`, etc.). How should I install these to my packages cache? And how should I reference them in my projects? Can I identify a default or base set of packages that are auto-added to every project? If I just install these with `install.packages()` will this get the job done?
5. How do I manage multiple versions of R? `pyenv` does a fantastic job of managing multiple versions of python. And `conda` conveniently treats python and R as any other package... If I want a specific version of R in my project, is there a way to `renv::install(r@3.4.4)`?